# Can we define inflection point to be the relative extremum of $f'$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, graphing-functions

In calculus, the inflection point of a function are treated either informally, or putting more attention on its intuition than precise definition. By making some observation, I come up with an idea that it seems that the inflection point can defined as the relative extremum of $f'$. I wonder if it's OK and make no difference with the intuitive meaning as everybody knows. And I also wonder if there are other definitions used by some people.

Comment: Could you explain it in more details? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind; I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming a smooth curve**

The curve $y=\mathrm f(x)$ has an inflexion when $\mathrm f''(x)=0$. The inflexion is called "ordinary" if $\mathrm f'''(x) \neq 0$ and "higher" if $\mathrm f'''(x)=0$. Some elementary texts require $\mathrm f'(x)=0$, but this is just an inflexion whose tangent line is horizontal. The curve $y=\sin x$ has an inflexion at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

An inflexion point is a point where a curve has unusually high-order contact with its tangent line.

A curve and its tangent line usually have order-2 contact, i.e. the simultaneous solution of the curve's equation and the tangent line's equation has a double root.

**For example:** Consider the curve $y=x^2$ and the tangent line $y=2x-1$ at $(x,y)=(1,1)$. Solving $y=x^2$ and $y=2x-1$ simultaneously gives 
$$2x-1=x^2 \iff x^2-2x+1=0 \iff (x-1)^2=0$$
This has a double root at $x=1$ and so the tangent line and curve have order-2 contact.

**For example:** The curve $y=x(x^2-1)$ has an inflexion at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. To see this, find the equation of the tangent line there: $y=-x$. Solving $y=x(x^2-1)$ and $y=-x$ simultaneously:
$$-x = x(x^2-1) \iff x^3=0$$
which has a triple root at $x=0$. So the curve and tangent line have order-3 contact at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and that point is an inflexion.

**For example:** The curve $y=\sin x$ has an inflexion at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. The tangent line is $y=x$ so we need the order of the root of $x-\sin x =0$. When $x=0$, clearly $0-\sin 0 =0$. We can differentiate to give $1-\cos x =0$, and this has a solution when $x=0$. We differentiate again to give $\sin x =0$ which has $x=0$ as a solution. Differentiating again gives $\cos x = 0$ which is false when $x=0$. This tells us that $x - \sin x =0$ has a triple root when $x=0$. (The equation $\mathrm g(x)=0$ has a root of order-$k$ if
$\mathrm g(x)=\mathrm g'(x)=\cdots =\mathrm g^{(k-1)}(x)=0$
and $\mathrm g^{(k)}(x) \neq 0$. )

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^4$ has $f''(0)=0$, but $0$ is not a point of inflection.

Comment: @egreg It depends on your definition of inflexion. The definition I use, in terms of contact with the tangent line, has $x=0$ as an inflexion of $y=x^4$, and indeed $y=x^n$ for all integers $n \ge 3$. See pages 22 and 23 of https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&lpg=PA23&ots=_TcfXi7zg5&dq=curves%20and%20singularities%20inflexion&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=curves%20and%20singularities%20inflexion&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Even just being a critical point of $f'$ does not guarantee an inflection point, which you can see with the function
$$
f(x)=cx^2
$$
$f'(x)=2cx$, $c\ne 0$ which is zero at the origin, but $f''(0)=2c\ne 0$ and so concavity does not change at the origin, as you would expect.

Comment: I see! On the other hand, so *ALL* critical points of $f$ will produce inflection points?

Comment: Actually re-reading what you wrote, it is not true. I will revise the above.

Comment: $0$ is not an inflection point for $x^4.$

Comment: @zhw. Oops I guess it's an undulation point

Comment: But I thought that as in the other posts answer an inflection point is just where f" is 0, instead there must be a change in curvature?